# An approach for computing distribution of $\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ X_i \le g(t) \}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a collection of i.i.d random variables $X_1,...,X_n$.
We are interested in computing the probability distribution of the following object
\begin{align}
\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ X_i \le g(t) \}}
\end{align}
where $g$ is some given function and $1_{ \{\cdot  \}}$ is the indicator function.

**Question:** I am interested in what is wrong with the following steps:

We observe that $1_{ \{ X_i \le g(t) \}}=b_{i,t}$  where $b_{i,t}$ is Bernoulli with success probability $p_t=P(X \le g(t))$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ X_i \le g(t) \}}&=\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} \sum_{i=1}^n b_{i,t}
\end{align}
Next, we note that sum of Bernoulli is binomial with parameter $n$ and success probability $p_t$. Therefore,

\begin{align}
\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ X_i \le g(t) \}}& \stackrel{d}{=}\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} B_{p_t}
\end{align}
where $B_{p_t}$ a Binomial random varaible with success probability $p_t$.

However, I have an issue with the last step. In particular,  assume that $p_t>0$ for $t \in (t_1,t_2)
$, then isn't it true that
\begin{align}
\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} B_{p_t}=0 \text{ a.s.} 
\end{align}

So something must have gone wrong, but I am not sure which step is wrong.

Comment: No, if $p_t > 0$ for $t \in (t_1,t_2)$ then it is not necessarily true that $\min_{t \in (t_1,t_2) B_{p_t} = 0$ a.s.  I don't see why you think something must have gone wrong, though.

Comment: @user6247850  Ok. Well here is my reasoning: $\{B_{p_t}\}_t$ is a process parameterized by a continuous index $t$. Therefore,  $\{B_{p_t}\}_t$ is set of uncountable cardinality.  The process takes finite many values on $\{0,...n \}$. Isn't the probability of getting a zero is equal to one. Therefore, the minimum would be zero.

Comment: Why is the probability of getting a zero $1$?  For example, if $p_t = 0.5$ for all $t \in (t_1,t_2)$ then of course the probability of getting a zero isn't equal to $1$.

Comment: @user6247850  So, I guess what I am not clear about is what is $\min_{t} B_t$.  Is it a minimum over a collection of random variables?  For example, if $p_t=t $ and $t_1=0.1$ and $t_2=0.5$. Would we get a zero?

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that
\begin{align}
\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} B_{p_t}=0 \text{ a.s.} 
\end{align}
For example, if $t_1 = t_2 = 0,5$
\begin{align}
\min_{ t \in [t_1,t_2]} B_{p_t} = B_{0,5} \ne 0 \text{ a.s.} 
\end{align}

We may write
\begin{align}
\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ X_i \le g(t) \}}
= \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ X_i \le \min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} g(t) \}}
\end{align}
because empirical distribution function is nondecreasing.

Comment: But would it be zero if $t_1 \neq t_2$ ?

Comment: @Boby, \begin{align}
\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ X_i \le g(t) \}}
= \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ X_i \le \min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} g(t) \}}
\end{align} is not zero, for example, in case, when $\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} g(t) = 0.5$

Comment: Sorry, I am asking about $\min_{t_1,t_2} B_{p_t}$.  I am wondering if the step $\min_t \sum_i 1_{X_i \le g(t) } = \min_{t}  \{  B_t \}$ is actually correct?

Comment: @Boby, this step means, that $\sum_i I_{X_i \le g(t)} = B_t \sim Bin(n, g(t))$ and it is true.

Comment: Ok. Thank you.  Do you know how to find the distribution of $\min_{p_1 \le p  \le p_2 } B_p$?   Does one use order statistics? But it's continuous.

Comment: $\min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ X_i \le g(t) \}}
= \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{ X_i \le \min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} g(t) \}} \sim Bin(n, a)$, where $a =  \min_{ t \in (t_1,t_2)} g(t)$. The answer is a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $a$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for clearing all this up.